# How to use noscript tag with ScriptBundle

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I've used scriptBundle in my code like this

```
var ideaGaugesBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Content/scripts/external/gauges/ideaGaugesBundle")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/gauges/gauges.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/gauges/raphael.js");
            ideaGaugesBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
            bundles.Add(ideaGaugesBundle);
```

and it's rendering on page by @Scripts.Render("~/Content/scripts/external/gauges/ideaGaugesBundle")

```
        <script src="/Content/scripts/external/gauges/gauges.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/scripts/external/gauges/raphael.js"></script>
```

how can I add noscript tag to each one on the fly?

```
    <script src="/Content/scripts/external/gauges/gauges.js"></script>
<noscript>It appears that javascript is not supported or disabled.</noscript>
    <script src="/Content/scripts/external/gauges/raphael.js"></script>
<noscript>It appears that javascript is not supported or disabled.</noscript>
```

Comment: Why do you need it on each one? Just add `<noscript>...</noscript>` to your base template.

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/Content/scripts/external/gauges/ideaGaugesBundle")
<noscript>It appears that javascript is not supported or disabled. Javascript must be enable for this feature to work.</noscript>

Comment: I mean, you don't need lots of them on your page, just one.

Comment: I added like that and check my html code in http://achecker.ca/ it said there is problem

Comment: Don't put it in the `head`, put it in the `body`.

Comment: it's in body and I still have problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
the problem was because I was in debug mode in release mode these are merging together and rendering like this

```
<script src="/Content/scripts/external/gauges/ideaGaugesBundle?v=aZoSAkEOJjHIoGeUE95SrTKdRXcx3_goCN4TVgrS9RY1"></script>
```